# Get merged branch back in Git

Tags: git, merge, bitbucket

I had a branch from master in Git. I merged it into master. Now due to some reasons I want that branch back. Is it possible? I was far behind the master. I want the merged branch for versioning.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply re-create your branch, starting from the second parent of the merge commit created when you merged your branch to master.

```
git checkout -B yourBranch merge_SHA1^2
```

- Replace merge_SHA1 with the SHA1 of the merge commit
- `^2` is for resetting your branch to the second parent of the commit that you merged to master

That is:

```
x--x--x--M (master)
        /
 y--y--y <- yourBranch is M^2 second parent of commit M
```

You could also consider starting your branch directly from the merge commit.

```
 git checkout -B yourBranch merge_SHA1^2
```

Meaning:

```
x--x--x--M (master)
        / \
 y--y--y   Y--Y--Y <- yourBranch reset zand starting from commit M
(your old branch)
```